# Call C function (libcanberra) from shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, command-line

I'd like to play a system sound in a Git hook for a [fun project](https://github.com/mika/commit-sounds/issues/1).

There's a [freedesktop standard](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/sound-theme-spec) and a C library ([libcanberra](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/libcanberra/)) for system sounds, but no executable coming with libcanberra. Is there an easy way to call the [ca_context_play](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/libcanberra/gtkdoc/libcanberra-canberra.html#ca-context-play) method of libcanberra from a shell script without starting a full perl or python interpreter? And if not, how would I to it with perl/python?

Comment: The libcanberra author pointed me to the command canberra-gtk-play that is included in the Debian package libcanberra-gtk0 and does what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just write a simple C program that calls the function through what you specify on the command line?

Comment: Second this advice, just do it. It's much more easier and interfaceable than anything else you might be imagining.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call a C function from shell (unless you develop plugins for the few shells -like zsh- accepting them; but then you won't have asked your question that way.).

You can only run a program from a shell, and you could write one, as the anonymous user112358132134 suggested.

There are several programs to play some sounds on Linux. On my Debian box, the [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) software provides the `play` command which does that.

Comment: hehe.. "the anonymous user112358132134".  it'd be something crazy if stackoverflow gave me that as my default name ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile C code before running it in shell, so it's not possible to directly invoke C functions from shell.

The command line only executes machine code. When you see it executes text(shell script or python script), it just invokes another program(like python virtual machine) which can execute text. So compilation language(like C or C++) cannot be directly executed.